# How to echo a variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I can't get the following to work, been trying ages now :(

```
Day: <input type="date" name="Day" value=""<?php $currentDate;?>"" /> 


Day: <input type="date" name="Day" value="2014-02-11" />
```

The second one works fine but the first one won't.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have a quotes problem and you are not echoing the value

instead of this :

```
value=""<?php $currentDate;?>""
```

try

```
value="<?php echo $currentDate ?>"
```

Comment: Related: [HTML/PHP display current date in html date input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36688388/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't yet defined the current date you can use:

```
Day: <input type="date" name="Day" value="<?=date('Y-m-d')?>" />
```

Otherwise:

```
Day: <input type="date" name="Day" value="<?=$currentDate?>" />
```

Comment: It will not work. You need to use `<? $currentDate; ?>` like in my answer

Comment: You don't need to use `=` in `"<?=$currentDate;?>"`

Comment: Yes you do. Otherwise you need to use `<?echo $currentDate;?>`