# HTML/PHP display current date in html date input

Tags: php, html

I am using a `date input` type to select a date in my PHP project.

Now everytime I submit the form I want to display the `date` in the input that has been selected.

This is what I've tried:

```
<?php $date = $_GET['date']; ?>
<input placeholder="<?php $date ?>" type="date" name="date" id="date"  />
```

But unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

Anyone has any idea if my goal is possible?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `$_GET['date']`? Did you var_dump it? Maybe it is an array from some other form?

Comment: How does your url looks like when you execute this code? Maybe you redirect after form submit or send data using POST?

Comment: You may want to use `<?php echo $date; ?>` instead.

Comment: @Paul I did dump it and it's fine

Comment: @Justinas No I am using a get request

Comment: Try to change input type `date` to `text`. Some browser don't take the placeholder of input type date

Comment: I have tried with date its work fine in my system.

Comment: @Alexis How can you select a date then?

Comment: Try $date = date("Y-m-d"); if its display then problem is in your get request. And also use 
echo or <?= $date ?>

Comment: @RuchishParikh Realy that's crazy??

Comment: Just for search where's the problem, you can change the input type.

Comment: It is showing the date when I change it to text

Comment: Then I think its create issue because of php version.

Comment: Okay, so it's due to browser, think you can show your date if you set the value of the input with your date, but placeholder on input type date don't work on some browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set a placeholder to `<input type="date"/>`. See the following information from HTML specification:

> The following content attributes must not be specified and do not apply to the element: accept, alt, checked, dirname, formaction, formenctype, formmethod, formnovalidate, formtarget, height, inputmode, maxlength, minlength, multiple, pattern, placeholder, size, src, and width.
>   https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#date-state-%28type=date%29

You have to set the date as `value` like the following:

```
<?php $date = $_GET['date']; ?>
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" value="<?= $date ?>" />
```

**An example code:**

```html
<input placeholder="2011-01-01" type="date" id="date"/>
<input value="2011-01-01" type="date" id="date"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo that variable, or else nothing will display.
Like this:

```
//Shorthand
<?=$date ?>
//Not shorthand with print
<?php print $date; ?>
//Not shorthand with echo
<?php echo $date; ?>
```

People would probably prefer echo instead of print.

Comment: @FrankLucas - It won't work if you haven't put anything in that $_GET variable. Go to the page you're testing and add ?date=thedate on the end of the URL. "thedate" should then be shown in the input field.

Comment: @stealthyninja It is not showing anything, unfortunately

Comment: @FrankLucas You could try and make it look like this, just for test: $date = date("d-m-Y");

Comment: @FrankLucas that is weird. Should work. Have you written it like this? http://pastebin.com/MMrh2bix

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the variable inside value

```
<?php 
$date = isset($_GET['date']) ? $_GET['date'] : ''; 
?>
<input value="<?php echo $date; ?>" type="date" name="date" id="date"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need check the form submission data first, before fetching the data in PHP. Request you to check form data and submission method.

I would like to suggest use $_REQUEST['date'] instead of $_GET.

If this does not work, let us see your form code?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers where the `echo` was mentioned as solution, you should add the following after `$date`:

`<?php $date = isset($_GET['date']) ? $_GET['date'] : false; ?>`

When `$date` is not found, this will result in not giving a warning message. If you don't, and the `$_GET['date']` can't be found you'll get a `undefined variable` warning message..